# post to another domain from cakephp controller

Tags: cakephp

Is it possible to POST to another domain from inside of a cake controller? I am collecting data and posting to the server and once confirmed it has saved I need to send the data out to another server. the other server is not running cake so just a POST to the other server's processing script page is where I need to send it.

I am already doing that via sending an ajax post then normal post one right after the other but I would rather wait until I have confirmed that the data has been stored before it is sent.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cakephp doesn't have a method to do so. That is not a normal flow of action, you should normally have a form that sends the data to the other domain script, does something and then you are redirected back to a page with the results either by cookie, by get or directly in the url path...

Still you have some ways to achieve that

My sugestion is that you use curl, that way you can send the post data to another domain page and maybe receive a json code that you can parse and understand.

Also you can use the get method insted of post to send the data to the other place and make sure the other place redirects you back. Or you can continue with the js solution. :)

also you can do it another way, opening a tcp connection and sending the request there...

Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks api55 this `http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl` was enough to get me started to what I needed to do using curl. Worked like a charm.